# Django Rest Framework поле end_time

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Задача такая -

В модели объекта Post имеется поле `created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Нужно создать еще одно поле end_time, в котором будет - сегодняшняя дата + 1 месяц вперед. А то есть, если создался пост, то у него будет в поле created сегодняшнее число (5 января 2020), а в поле end_time будет на месяц вперед (5 февраля 2020). 
Плюс также должно быть поле is_actual, в котором будет True, если end_time дата не наступила. False, соответсвенно, наоборот.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Поле `end_time` можно определить с значением по умолчанию в виде функции:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

def next_month():
    now = timezone.now()
    return now + relativedelta(months=+1)


class Post(models.Model):
    ... 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=next_month, blank=True, editable=False)
```

Для определения дельты я использую [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html#module-dateutil.relativedelta). Похожий результат можно получить с использованием `timedelta` из стандартного [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

С полем `is_actual` сложнее. Придется с некоторой периодичностью обновлять записи в БД.

Если хранение `end_time` и `is_actual` в БД необязательно можно получить эти значения в виде свойств объекта `Post`:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def end_time(self):
        return self.created + relativedelta(months=+1)

    @property
    def is_actual(self):
        return timezone.now() < self.end_time
```

В сериализаторе будут доступны с соответсвующими именами:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (...остальные поля, 'end_time', 'is_actual')
```

Если эти значения требуются только в сериализаторе можно вынести логику туда:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.utils import timezone
from rest_framework import serializers

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    end_time = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_actual = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (...остальные поля, 'end_time', 'is_actual')

    def get_end_time(self, obj):
        return obj.created + relativedelta(months=+1)

    def get_is_actual(self, obj):
        return timezone.now() < obj.created + relativedelta(months=+1)
```

Comment: Привет! Благодарю за ответ! Это то что нужно, но как теперь использовать фильтр? К примеру, я хочу теперь вывести все объекты, у которых is_actual == True. Как только я добавляю эти поля в filterset_fields, то вылетает ошибка Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: end_time

Comment: Как можно делать обращение к БД на изменение is_actual?

Comment: добавил в [следующий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067354/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b/1067371#1067371)