# Отфильтровать по окончанию даты

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Задача такая -

Есть два поля в модели Post:

```
def next_month():
    now = timezone.now()
    return now + relativedelta(months=+1)

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=next_month, blank=True, editable=False)
```

Мы получаем все объекты по url - api/v1/posts/

Но оттуда нужно убрать те объекты, где end_time уже настал (now() > end_time).

Как это реализовать? Можно ли как-то через queryset это реализовать, в самом ViewSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно добавить кастомный менеджер для модели `Post`:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now


class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def is_actual(self):
        return self.filter(end_time__gt=Now())


class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=next_month, blank=True, editable=False)

    objects = PostManager()
```

и обновить `queryset` для `ViewSet`:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.is_actual()
    ...
```

Comment: Привет! Спасибо большое за правильный ответ.
А как можно реализовать, чтобы отображалось что уже не актуально? :) Тут по сути метод is_actual возвращает true в кверисете. А как сделать, чтобы отображалось только где is_actual == false?